# How to fix IntelliJ IDEA's SDK after it got "corrupted" that leads to "{class} cannot be found"?

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

Due to a separate issue in intellij (adding python module corrupts scala/java project), I need to revive/fix the scala/java SDK.

As can be seen in first  screenshot even basic java classes e.g.

```
IllegalArgumentException
```

can not be found

But the SDK is already present/not missing (as shown in second screenshot). I have already done

> ```
> File | Invalidate caches.
> ```

That did not help.

So .. how to reset / clean INtellij SDK's after it got confused/corrupted?

I am using 13.1.5 ultimate.

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried 14? I recently upgraded to 14 (community) and everything is working (also upgraded scala plugin). I had once with 13 the problem that you have, I do not remember what I did to fix, I might invalidate cache and restarted.

Comment: Unfortunately  Spark does not work properly on IJ14 due to the quasiquotes/paradise plugin issue. Also as mentioned in OP I already did invalidate cache/restart and it had no effect .

Comment: oh!  It works now!  I had tried several times in the past, and as recently as the end of december 2014 (< 4 weeks ago). It is working now for spark builds.  I am not going to bother to try to use both python and scala together though.

Comment: good! Although I found 14 a little bit slower than 13 especially for scala.

Comment: @javadba Would you mind posting the comment of yours as an answer and accept? That's going to help others who run into the issue and see the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @JacekLaskowski  I do not have an answer for the mixed scala/python. For now I gave up on trying to do so. It would still be v helpful if an answer were found.

Comment: Can you link *"Due to a separate issue in intellij"* to the issue if you know it? Thanks!