# How to define/install Scala facet in IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.x?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, typesafe-activator

In [How to fix IntelliJ IDEA's SDK after it got "corrupted" that leads to "{class} cannot be found"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28132765/1305344) I found screenshots with Scala facet (and Python one). I don't have it nor can I define one myself.

[image: Invalid Scala facets]

How can I define or install a Scala facet in IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.2 or the latest 14.0.3 EAP with the latest respective version of the Scala plugin?

[image: No Scala facet to add]

My usual approach to work with sbt/Scala projects in IDEA is to import a sbt/Scala project after it's created using Typesafe Activator.

Comment: I think the Scala facet was removed with v14.0 and replaced with the possibility of adding a Scala SDK in the project structure dialog. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298176/unknown-type-of-facet-scala-in-intellij-14 where it is explained - there is also a link to a post on the Scala plugin's blog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr** [There's no Scala facet in IntelliJ IDEA 14.](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2014/10/30/scala-plugin-update-for-intellij-idea-14-rc-is-out/)

[As @PermaFrost correctly pointed out in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137320/how-to-define-install-scala-facet-in-intellij-idea-14-0-x?noredirect=1#comment44648360_28137320), IntelliJ IDEA 14 has introduced ["Rethinking the project configuration model"](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2014/10/30/scala-plugin-update-for-intellij-idea-14-rc-is-out/), i.e.:

> Another change is that we’ve finally decided to get rid of the Scala facet and replace it with so called Scala SDK library that, in addition to the standard Scala libraries, has a classpath to Scala compiler